# Not able to start broker

Tags: messagebroker

I have installed Webspher mesage broker 8.0.0.0 on AIX 6.1.
When I try to start the broker by issuing an mqsistart command, I get :

BIP8875W: The component verification for 'NSPZPAI1' has finished, but one or more checks failed.
One or more of the component verification checks failed.
Check the error log for preceding error messages.

To diagnose this, when I run mqsicvp, I get this description:

BIP8873I: Starting the component verification for component 'NSPZPAI1'.
BIP8876I: Starting the environment verification for component 'NSPZPAI1'.
BIP8894I: Verification passed for 'Registry'.
BIP8892E: Verification failed. The installed Java level 'sh: java:  not found.
BIP8894I: Verification passed for 'MQSI_FILEPATH'.
BIP8877W: The environment verification for component 'NSPZPAI1' has finished, but one or more checks failed.
BIP8882I: Starting the WebSphere MQ verification for component 'NSPZPAI1'.
BIP8886I: Verification passed for queue 'SYSTEM.BROKER.ADMIN.QUEUE' on queue manager 'NSPZPAI1'.
BIP8886I: Verification passed for queue 'SYSTEM.BROKER.EXECUTIONGROUP.QUEUE' on queue manager 'NSPZPAI1'.
BIP8886I: Verification passed for queue 'SYSTEM.BROKER.EXECUTIONGROUP.REPLY' on queue manager 'NSPZPAI1'.
BIP8884I: The WebSphere MQ verification for component 'NSPZPAI1' has finished successfully.
BIP8875W: The component verification for 'NSPZPAI1' has finished, but one or more checks failed.

Can someone please advise how can I resolve the "BIP8892E: Verification failed. The installed Java level 'sh: java:  not found." error?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your java environment.
Verify your installation / java version and open a PMR (Problem Management Record) at ibm.com.

Answer (score 0):

This message:

The installed Java level 'sh: java: not found

Indicates that Java was not on your path when you executed mqsistart. Since the mqsiprofile script sets up java for you I suspect you ahvent run the profile script in this shell environment before running mqsistart.